# NodeJsApp - Unable to make successful http connections

Tags: node.js

I'm as new to Node and when I trying to run my first ever simple  node app that makes an http connection to `www.google.com` host. While I tried some of the solutions suggested on prior threads nothing really seemed to help. While the below error is not a rare case but need someone to advise me what's missing from my setup/env.

**source code - test.js - as simple as below** -

```
var http = require('http');
var options = { host: 'www.google.com'};
http.get(options, function(err, res) {
console.log("GOT ERR?", err);
console.log("GOT RES?", res);});
```

I get the below error.

```
events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
         ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Comment: DNS lookup is failing.  Find out why.

Comment: Josh, Not sure if you are directing me to another location that probably has the issue fix. Do let me know if you have the root cause of the error 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND' during the http.get call.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback is wrong. Try to write your code as follow:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = { host: 'www.google.com'};

// notice that the callback only receives a res parameter
// errors are handled on an event below
var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
});

// handle errors
req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Here is the documentation for http.get: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

The error that you are seeing (throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event) is because you do not have an even handler for the error event. Notice the req.on('error') in my code to address this.

Comment: This is all very true, but still does not address the actual cause of the error: the failed DNS lookup.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. With the revised code segment , I get the below - Got error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND . Really need help on resolving this issue.

Comment: Hector, Thanks for your reply. Would you know what's causing this getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND issue ? This is the core issue here.

Comment: Basically, I'm unable to hit any host. just not google.

Comment: I think the root of the problem is DNS as @josh3736 pointed out.

Comment: Thank you, Hector. How to proceed resolving this issue. Really need clues on this. I couldn't see a post clearly explaning this part of the issue.

Comment: The proxy is not blocking the request either. we have set the proxy using npm config too. Not sure if we are missing any basic config setups. Any help is appreciated. TU.